# How to match and return part of an HTML file in ASP

Tags: regex, asp-classic

I'm looking to match a part of several HTML files that get passed into a loop in an ASP file and then return that part of the HTML files to include in my output. Here's my code so far:

```
<%for i=0 to uBound(fileIDs) ' fileIDs is an array of URLs
    dim srcText, outText, url
    Set ex = New RegExp
    ex.Global = true
    ex.IgnoreCase = true
    ex.Pattern = "<section>[\S\s]+</section>" ' This finds the HTML I want
    url = fileIDs(i)
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    xmlhttp.open "GET", url, false
    xmlhttp.send ""
    srcText = xmlhttp.responseText
    outputText = ex.Execute(mediaSrcText) ' I expect this to be the HTML I want
    Response.Write(outputText.Item(0).Value) ' This would then return the first instance
    set xmlhttp = nothing
next %>
```

I've tested the regular expression on my files and it's matching the parts that I want it to.

when I run the page containing this code, I get an error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01b6'
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

on the line with ex.Execute. I've also tried ex.Match, but got the same error. So I'm clearly missing the proper method for returning the match so I can write it out into the file. What is that method? Or am I approaching the problem from the wrong direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `Set` when you're assigning `outputText`:

```
Set outputText = ex.Execute(mediaSrcText)
```

I should probably also say that you really shouldn't be using regular expressions to attempt to parse HTML, although I don't know enough about the context to offer more specific advice.

Comment: Thanks! That got me moved forward to a new error at least. Moving on!

Comment: Sadly I don't have access to a Classic ASP environment at the moment, otherwise I would probably have been able to take it a bit further :-)